# Setting bound for an infinite expected value

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, expectation

Say $X=2^Z$ and $Z$ is a geometric random variable with $p=1/2$.

It follows that, $E[X] = \infty$

So setting the upper bound by the markov inequality, $$P(X \geq t) \leq \frac{E[X]}{t} = \frac{\infty}{t}$$ for some value $t$.

However, this doesn't make much sense since we know the maximum probability is $1$.

Any advice on how to estimate the upper bound probability $P(X \geq t)$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to estimate the probability $\mathbb P(X\geqslant t)$ if the expectation of $X$ is infinite, isn't it? Do you have other information?

Comment: Yes I'd like to estimate the probability, $X = 2^Z$ where $Z$ is a geometric random variable with $p=1/2$. Hence why $E[X] = \infty$

Comment: @johnny: it is better to add it to the problem, because in such a formulation it does not make much sense. If we only know that the expected value of a r.v. $X$ is infinite, we cannot say anything on the rate of convergence to zero of $\int_{x}^{+\infty}f(t)\,dt$, where $f$ is the pdf of $X$. But in your case, you know the distribution of $X$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio updated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Markov inequality still holds, it just isn't useful here. For your specific example though, $Z$ takes values in $1,2,3,\ldots$ so $X$ takes values in $2,4,8,\ldots$, and
$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\mathbb P(2^Z = k)=\mathbb P(Z=\lg k)=\left(\frac12\right)^{\lg k}, k=2,4,8,\ldots. $$
(where $\lg$ denotes base-$2$ logarithm). If $t>0$, let $n=\min\{k\geqslant 1 : \lg k\geqslant t \}.$ Then
$$\mathbb P(X\geqslant t)=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\mathbb P(X=2^k)=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^k=\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}. $$

Comment: Great answer, but shouldn't the probability depend on $t$ ? In other words, shouldn't $P(X>2)$ be different from $P(X>3)$ ? thanks

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the smallest positive integer greater than or equal to $2^t$.